# Can a M1 Macbook Pro run the ARM version of Windows 11 and compile Visual Studio .Net 4+ projects?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows-11, .net-framework, arm

I cant seem to find any information if you can run Visual Studio 2022 on an M1 Mac and compile the older .Net 4.7.2 project on the ARM version of Windows 11.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quick update:

I now have an M1X Macbook Pro running Windows 11 ARM via Parallels
With VS 2022 and it's possible to run older .Net projects (Web forms/MVC) I have tested and run projects from 4.5 - 4.8

Everything runs and builds.

Comment: Thats the answer i was looking for! It is the running/compiling speed acceptable?

Comment: Thank you, great news! Was looking several times for the answer. What about performance of VS? Is it possible to work with it  whole day or it becomes quite slow and can be used just for builds? What is configuration of your MacBook? Just thinking if it will be possible to do the same with MacBook M1 16 Ram.

Comment: I have 32GB of RAM with the M1X pro 24 core chip. The build speed is fast, compared to what I had before. 2min build time down to about 15 seconds. 
I will admit I took a gamble on this but it paid off.

Comment: VS 2022 is running on x86 emulation inside ARM. It's not natively ARM

Comment: @phuclv is correct, but the main point is that VS 2022 is running.

Comment: Can I ask: have you tried running the ARM version of VS2022, and if so what was your experiences? I have many legacy Framework applications I need to maintain (including some Webforms applications), and I'm curious to know if it's possible and/or practical to use VS2022-for-ARM?

Comment: Now running the ARM version of VS 2022 Preview everything is fine. even builds older .Net 4.6 projects

Answer (score 1):

> I cant seams to find any information if you can run Visual Studio 2019 and compile .Net 4.7.2 project via the ARM version of Windows 10.

Visual Studio 2019 only runs on x86 systems. You can use Visual Studio Code to compile .NET (Core) 5 projects. .NET 4.7.2 isn’t installed on Windows 10 (or specifically for several years now) but on x86 hardware you have targeting packs that allow you to target a specific version of the .NET Framework.

Worth pointing out that .NET 5 natively supports ARM.  You can also compile ARM .NET Framework projects on x86 hardware.

> Visual Studio is built to target processors based on the x86 architecture, and there are no versions of Visual Studio for ARM-based processors.

Source: [Visual Studio on ARM-powered devices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-on-arm-devices?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I have seen VS 2019 running on the ARM version of Windows 10. I know is all emulation just wanted to know if I can get any of my old VS 4.7 projects to compile before I go buy a M1 mac

Comment: @TheAlbear - [What you saw running was Visual Studio running on x86 emulation on Windows 10 for ARM.  However, Visual Studio 2019 only specifically runs on x86 or AMD/x64 processors, per Microsoft's own documentation.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-on-arm-devices?view=vs-2019). **Worth pointing out that .NET 4.7.2 cannot run on Windows 10 for ARM.** All that means is you cannot compile .NET Framework 4.7.2 projects on ARM devices.

Comment: I know it's all done under emulation, But the question was more IF I go get an M1 mac, install Windows 10 ARM. Run VS 2019 under x86 emulation. will it compile a current .Net 4.7 project

Comment: @TheAlbear - You cannot compile a .NET 4.7 project on an ARM device.  .NET 4.7 cannot be installed on Windows 10 for ARM.  My answer and my previous comment made that crystal clear.

Comment: You also won't be able to run VS2019 on Windows 10 on ARM.